# jQuery selector for returning an array of ids that match this criteria

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Adopting a project from a co-worker :-( I have the following markup and would like to populate a with data from an ajax call to return some data. How would I get the following array `[925,927,928]` so that I could iterate over it.

```
<div class="query-social" data-global-id="925"></div>
<div class="query-social" data-global-id="927"></div>
<div class="query-social" data-global-id="928"></div>
```

How would I be able to get a list of data-global-ids that satisfy the criteria .query-social? Most examples I found were one off.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var globalIDs = $('.query-social').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('global-id');
}).get();
```

Comment: this looks right. is data the standard for passing info like this? like data-user-id. sorry for naive questions. haven't touched jquery in awhile

Comment: @timpone `jQuery().data` attempts to parse the value of the element. If you only want to get the attribute, use `.attr("data-global-id")`. Otherwise, use `.data("global-id")`.

Comment: @Rob W, thx, this tutorial also helped http://www.learningjquery.com/2011/09/using-jquerys-data-apis . Is there any issue with browser support for this syntax?

Comment: jQuery is designed to support as much browsers as possible. The code will only fail if you forget to load the jQuery framework.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to select the real attribute, rather than a (parsed) property, use:

```
var list = $(".query-social[data-global-id]").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("data-global-id");
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
$('div.query-social').each(function (i, el) {
    arr.push($(el).attr('data-global-id')));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5VGCS/

or map

```
var arr = $("div.query-social").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("data-global-id");
}).get();
```